# How to call method from another class

Tags: java, netbeans

It has been a long time since I used java and I have run into a problem.
I need to load test cases from a file and then run them.
The problem is that I need to call a method "shippingCost" from another class "Function.class" This is a compiled code, no source.

How do I call this from my class, "FunctionTest.java" inside of the public static void main.

Thanks!

The class, and the error msg.

[image: Classes]

[image]

Comment: If the method is non-static, then create an object of the class and call the method off of this object. If the method is static, then simply call the method off of the class. If this doesn't make sense to you, then you should be studying the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) first before asking questions here. There is a wealth of information to be found there.

Comment: I thought for a minute that I was typing it wrong, but I was trying to do what people have posted. I think the problem is that I do not have the source code so I get errors finding the method?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you need to import that Function class.

Comment: One problem is that your initial question didn't give us near enough information. You asked a very vague and generic question on "how to call a method", but your problem isn't this at all, but rather one of getting an error message when you try. When this happens,  you need to show your code and show the error message. Else we have no idea what you may be doing wrong. Luck.

Comment: Thank you, it has been a couple years since I have used java and I always had the source when I did use it. Thought I was calling the method wrong to begin with and I had no idea I needed to set the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the 'Function.class' file into the Libraries folder of your project.
2. Put an import statement with the correct package of 'Function' class into your FunctionTest.java file: `import xx.xx.Function;` (Netbeans should be able to do that automatically on command.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the source in order to call the method, all you need is the compiled class.  As long as you can access the method (generally if it's public) then you should be able to call it.  An IDE like eclipse will even be able to help you find out which methods are available on an instance of the class.

So in the simplest case, you just create an instance of the class and then call the method.

```
Function func = new Function();
func.callMethod();
```

Further help would be giving us the error message so we would know which type of problem you are actually having.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to an instance of the object and invoke its methods.

```
Function function = new Function();
function.myFunction();
```

Your naming scheme leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: This is still very bad.  You have a class named Function with an instance method called Function() with a capital "F".  This violates the Sun Java coding standards and will confuse compilers and other programmers alike.  That usually means "constructor".  This is absolutely wrong-headed.  I'll change my answer to illustrate the way you should do it.

Comment: I originally posted it wrong. It was suppose to be a class "Function" with method "shippingCost", separate class "FunctionTest". Sorry if that confused anyone.